# Push git submodule changes to my own repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've just started using git submodules for my Android application by following this [guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

I've successfully cloned the repo and changed a few things to suit the needs of my application, but I can't push those changes back to my repo.

`git status` says there is modified content in my submodule, but I can't just `git add` that folder and push it?

If I try to push from the submodule directory it actually tries to push and gives me access denied since I'm not a contributor of that repo.

I want to be able to fetch the new changes from time to time, but to be able to keep and merge the small code that I modified every time that I try to update the submodule.

What would be the best approach in order to achieve this? Do I have to change the push remote origin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question it seems that your submodule (say `proj-dep`) is technically an external library.

Let us say that the code of `proj-dep` is hosted at https://github.com/vendor/proj-dep and you have mapped this path to your submodule.

However, you are not simply using `proj-dep` as is, you are using a modified version of the same.

You should be creating your own fork of https://github.com/vendor/proj-dep to https://github.com/alex/proj-dep and map this second path to your submodule.

You will be able to push your own changes to this fork. Also, you can pull changes from vendor's `proj-dep` as and when needed and merge/rebase your fork (eventually pulling them down to your submodule path).

Answer (score -1):

The changes in the submodule need to be added/commited/pushed first, at the submodule level. Then at the super level you can simply add the folder and commit/push.

Comment: When I'm trying to push at submodule level it tries to push to the remote that I have cloned from and I don;t want this. I want to keep my changes just for my own repo since they are not relevant to the original submodule.

Comment: Yes you should push to a different remote and periodically pull from the original remote to stay up to date with their changes.